# Using Node.js headless browser with selenium hybrid?

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am curious to know whether anyone out there have tried mixing node.js headless browser packages like zombie.js (any other alternatives?) and selenium browser for testing web applications.

I am attracted to node.js headless browser packages because it's lighter and much faster than driving a full browser via selenium. However, none of the headless browser node packages seem to support accurate rendering of html pages with javascript.

So what about combining best of the both worlds? Revert to using selenium to render pages that zombie.js can't render? How do you go about accomplishing the latter? You'd need to know when a page has not rendered successfully on zombie.js and fire the page on selenium browser. However, wouldn't this create lag in waiting for selenium to bootup?

More importantly, what's the best headless browser node.js package besides zombie.js? Focus should be on page rendering. Do you think we'll ever see a node.js headless browser package replacing selenium in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a headless testing tool called [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) that is very good at rendering. However, it's not a Node.js package.

I'm also hoping it will be ported to Node.js soon, of find some other package.

Comment: oh. my. god. this is very very interesting. any sources on how it renders pages with heavy javascript and such? if this is not nodejs, what is it really? just javascript? this is very interesting!

Comment: I guess the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart) would give you some info. It's more like a headless WebKit browser that you run its CLI to perform actions that you normally would on a browser. It's not just for testing, but for scraping and other useful purposes too. I just want a headless test tool, so I haven't looked into it much.